# Animation is too choppy when animating inline SVG with javascript according to the window's scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg

I am trying to use JavaScript to retrieve inline SVG elements and set their transform attributes in order to translate them in response to scrolling down the screen. I am using `window.requestAnimationFrame()` in order to do so.

The animation is very choppy so far and I haven't found a solution to remedy this yet. Any suggestions??

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0px">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1440 1024" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="">
        <g id="AbstractBackground">
            <rect id="backgroundRect" width="1440" height="1024" fill="#BDD8DE"/>
            <rect id="greenCircleGrad" x="-338" y="-444" width="1440" height="1440" fill="url(#paint0_radial_2005_534273)"/>
            <path id="wave1" d="M516 228.015C212 228.015 74 34.0154 -170 36.0154C-414 38.0154 -634 228.015 -634 228.015V988.015H1692V200.015C1692 200.015 1459 36.0154 1208 36.0154C957 36.0153 820 228.015 516 228.015Z" fill="#60AB9E"/>
            <rect id="turquoiseCircleGrad" x="508" y="-208" width="1440" height="1440" fill="url(#paint1_radial_2005_534273)"/>
            <path id="wave2" d="M872 553.015C568 553.015 430 359.015 186 361.015C-58 363.015 -278 553.015 -278 553.015V1313.02H2048V525.015C2048 525.015 1815 361.015 1564 361.015C1313 361.015 1176 553.015 872 553.015Z" fill="#77ABBB"/>
            <rect id="blueCircleGrad" x="-128" y="-42" width="1440" height="1440" fill="url(#paint2_radial_2005_534273)"/>
            <path id="wave3" d="M376 853.015C72 853.015 -66 659.015 -310 661.015C-554 663.015 -774 853.015 -774 853.015V1613.02H1552V825.015C1552 825.015 1319 661.015 1068 661.015C817 661.015 680 853.015 376 853.015Z" fill="#C6DAD4"/>
            <rect id="blackCircleGrad" x="207" y="221" width="1753" height="1753" fill="url(#paint3_radial_2005_534273)"/>
        <defs>
            <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_2005_534273" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(382 276) rotate(90) scale(720)">
                <stop stop-color="#7B3A5D" stop-opacity="0.67"/>
                <stop stop-color="#6DA060" stop-opacity="0.83"/>
                <stop offset="0.442708" stop-color="#6DA360" stop-opacity="0.71"/>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#6CA95D" stop-opacity="0"/>
            </radialGradient>
            <radialGradient id="paint1_radial_2005_534273" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1228 512) rotate(90) scale(720)">
                <stop stop-color="#71EFE3"/>
                <stop stop-color="#71EFE3"/>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#71EFE3" stop-opacity="0"/>
            </radialGradient>
            <radialGradient id="paint2_radial_2005_534273" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(592 678) rotate(90) scale(720)">
                <stop stop-color="#8A78B1"/>
                <stop stop-color="#58B4C8"/>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#67C0D4" stop-opacity="0"/>
            </radialGradient>
            <radialGradient id="paint3_radial_2005_534273" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1083.5 1097.5) rotate(90) scale(876.5)">
                <stop stop-color="#8A78B1" stop-opacity="0.73"/>
                <stop stop-color="#20665E" stop-opacity="0.53"/>
                <stop offset="0.713542" stop-color="#2F9262" stop-opacity="0"/>
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    </body>

    <script>

        // IDs of SVG elements in the SVG background that animate when scrolling down
        const SLO_SCROLL_TRANSFORM_IDS = ["turquoiseCircleGrad","wave1"];
        const MED_SCROLL_TRANSFORM_IDS = ["blueCircleGrad","wave2"];
        const FST_SCROLL_TRANSFORM_IDS = ["blackCircleGrad","wave3"];
        const [SLO_SCROLL_DIST, MED_SCROLL_DIST, FST_SCROLL_DIST] = [50, 100, 200];

        /**
         * applies css translate transformation to an svg element
         * @param id svg element id to apply transformation to
         * @param distance vertical distance to translate svg element
         */
        function translateSvgVertically(id, distance) {
            document.querySelector("svg #"+id).setAttribute('transform',"translate(0,"+distance+")");
        }

        let h = document.documentElement;
        let b = document.body;
        /**
         * returns how much of the page has been scrolled through as a decimal
         * @returns {number} returns a decimcal [0,1]
         */
        function getScrollFraction() {
            return (h['scrollTop']||b['scrollTop']) / ((h['scrollHeight']||b['scrollHeight']) - h.clientHeight);
        }

        let lastKnownScrollFraction = 0;
        let ticking = false;

        document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
            lastKnownScrollFraction = getScrollFraction();

            if (!ticking) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                    SLO_SCROLL_TRANSFORM_IDS.forEach((id) => translateSvgVertically(id, SLO_SCROLL_DIST*lastKnownScrollFraction));
                    MED_SCROLL_TRANSFORM_IDS.forEach((id) => translateSvgVertically(id, MED_SCROLL_DIST*lastKnownScrollFraction));
                    FST_SCROLL_TRANSFORM_IDS.forEach((id) => translateSvgVertically(id, FST_SCROLL_DIST*lastKnownScrollFraction));
                    ticking = false;
                });
                ticking = true;
            }
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

[image: gif of choppy animation of waves]

Comment: doesn't look "choppy" to me ... what browser and version, what operating system

Comment: I tried firefox 103.0 (64-bit) and Chrome 103.0.5060.134 (64-bit) on windows 11. Admittedly on chrome it only seems choppy if you scroll by clicking on the scroll bar. It's fine when I use the mousewheel on chrome.

Comment: looks fine on firefox and chrome regardless of how I scroll - mousewheel or "clicking on scroll bar"

Comment: hmm interesting

Comment: I just added a gif of what it looks like in my chrome browser